# Cannot connect to WIFI

Tags: centos, drivers, wifi

I finally made the switch from windows to Linux. CentOS to be precise. Unfortunately, I am unable to have my wireless connection working, so accessing the web is a hassle. Following directions on the web i was directed to

```
yum install wireless-tools
```

It says "Package 1:wireless-tools-29-5.1.1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version"

I was also directed to

```
sudo ifconfig -a
```

which resulted in

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B8:88:E3:34:E5:07  
      inet addr:192.168.0.155  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::ba88:e3ff:fe34:e507/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:397682 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:229592 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:578549471 (551.7 MiB)  TX bytes:17894242 (17.0 MiB)
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:98 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:98 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:7154 (6.9 KiB)  TX bytes:7154 (6.9 KiB)
```

people say that wlan0 is supposed to be there too. but I don't know how to get it in there.

```
lspci -v
```

the result

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)
Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8195
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
Memory at f2d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-91-81-fe-ff-4c-e0-00
0c:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5000
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
Memory at f1404000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at f1400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number dd-43-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
```

Comment: Check the manual over here. http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-network-config-wireless.html

Comment: @Ramesh, I already went through that. didnt help

Comment: @WarrenYoung I would like to become a Linux Admin. I am just getting into Hadoop which is based on linux(mostly centOS) so i figured i should play around with it.

Comment: CentOS can be used as desktop OS but there are better ones, I strongly recommend Linux Mint. CentOS is more focused on Server platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CentOS 6 runs a pretty old kernel, being a stable[*] Linux distribution that is now about 3 years old. Yes, CentOS 6 still gets updates, but they deliberately do not upgrade the kernel any more than they have to. (It's still running 2.6.32, whereas current is 3.14.)

There is a chance that you could [download and compile a newer Intel WiFi driver](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi), but even that can be difficult when the gap between the kernel you're using and the kernel the driver was first developed for gets so large.

This is why I suggested trying Fedora or the [RHEL 7 release candidate](http://www.redhat.com/about/news/archive/2014/4/red-hat-enterprise-linux-7-release-candidate-now-publicly-available) on that machine. Simply having a newer kernel may solve the problem.

There's nothing about Hadoop or wanting to become a Linux admin that requires that you use CentOS 6.  RHEL 7 will be out soon, and CentOS 7 should follow soon thereafter. Unless you're looking to jump into maintaining a set of existing CentOS 6 boxes, you might as well start learning the newer tech anyway.

Another good option is to run CentOS 6 in a [VM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) underneath an OS that *does* support your wireless network interface. Linux runs great in VMs.

---

[*] "Stable" as opposed to a bleeding edge Linux distro, the sort that will adopt newer tech with less vetting, and therefore less delay.